# Data Analysis with Python to Find Most Effective Column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis

I have an excel table with one result column, and about 8 9 column whice are affects the result. I know some machine leearning methods such as linear regression and polynomial reg, but not an expert.

Which method should I use to find out which column affects the result responsively?

My table have 3000 data (rows), 1 result col, and 9 Effective col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend one of the following:

## Unsupervised Dimension Reduction

Step 1 see if there is one or two obvious columns by using dimension reduction techniques such as [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html). After runnnig PCA you can look at the `explained_variance_ratio_` to se how much of the variance is explained by each component. If you are lucky most of the variance is included in one or two directions. You can look at the `singular_values_` to see which columns these correspond to.

## Supervised ML technique

Simplest to use is [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) library (XGBRegressor or XGBClassifier depending on your task), train it and look at the [feature_importance](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.feature_importances_). This will directly tell you which columns were most used to create the classifier.

Comment: ty for your comment, after I applied these methods. I'll give feedback!

Comment: I applied Supervised ML tech with XGBoost, and that works. Thx